# Uniswap Rinkeby Token Pairs Don't Exist

Tags: uniswap, rinkeby

I am putting together a demo contract which swap some token pairs on Uniswap. I'm testing my contract on Rinkeby. I don't care which token pairs to run the demo on. I grabbed multiple token addresses from [Etherscan](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tokentxns?p=1). To check if the token pair exists i'm running:

```
 address pairAddress = IUniswapV2Factory(factory).getPair(token0, token1);
 // make sure the pair exists in uniswap
 require(pairAddress != address(0), 'Could not find pool on uniswap');
```

The check fails on every token pair I try. **Are there any Uniswap token pairs on Rinkeby?**

Answer (score 0):

There's only a few pairs on Rinkeby, as seen on the Uniswap Interface:

[image]

I was able to swap my ETH for UNI and DAI (I think the *no symbol* just means there's no official logo for that token on the Rinkeby network).